# Array for one element in Array of json, Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input json:

```json
{
  "ListArray": [
    {
      "address": "address1",
      "contact": "123456789",
      "bpId": 123
    },
    {
      "address": "address2",
      "contact": "135792468",
      "bpId": 456
    },
    {
      "address": "address3",
      "contact": "246812356",
      "bpId": 678
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am using the below spec expression  :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ListArray": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Giving me this kind of output:

```json
{
 "Address_list": ["address1","address2","address3"],
 "Contact_list": ["123456789","135792468","246812356"],
 "Id_list": [123,456,678]
}
```

**But**, If the input (array of jsons) has only one json, for example:

```json
{
  "ListArray": [
    {
      "address": "address1",
      "contact": "123456789",
      "bpId": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I am getting the following output

```json
{
  "Address_list": "address1",
  "Contact_list": "123456789",
  "Id_list": 123
}
```

For one element, an array isn't forming. I want the output to be in an array even if there is only one element.
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a slight change, which is appending `.[]` to the currently existing ampersand(`&`), will resolve this such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ListArray": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```